# How to extract data about in-game events?

Tags: c++, modding

I recently started playing New World, and I thought I would like to create something like a "data collector".

It would report data like: during the session,

- I fired X bullets,
- type of bullets: Y,
- price of bullets: z,

...but I can't find information about downloading "data" from the game without using an API.

My question is:

Is it possible to extract data from the game without using a dedicated API?

Comment: Have you looked into memory-scanning tools like CheatEngine? It's up to you to figure out where in memory to look, but any data the game uses will be there somewhere at some point.